# Jquery Autocomplete not attaching to text input box

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jquery autocomplete plugin but am having trouble getting it to attach to my textarea #message or #messageid, (two different ones). It works when I set the function attach() to the onClick events of either element but if I execute it normally, or use $(document).ready(attach()) it doesn't seem to do anything.

This is the culled code of a page I made to try and debug it that retains the issue (the real page is fairly complex, split into a few files)

Thanks!

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(attach())

function attach(){
$("#messageid").autocomplete({

    source: function(request, response){
        $.post("utilities/atuser.php", {data: request}, function(data){

            alert(data);

            });


        },
    appendTo: "#content"
});

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="utilities/s_shoutout.php" method="post" id="sideshoutout" class="frmshoutout">

    <textarea name="message" cols="25" id="messageid" onclick=";"></textarea>
 <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Why are you doing an autocomplete on a textarea and not a text input?

Comment: The real one is a text input, that was a two second mockup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Following one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#messageid").autocomplete({ 

        source: function(request, response){ 
            $.post("utilities/atuser.php", {data: request}, function(data){ 

                alert(data); 

                }); 


            }, 
        appendTo: "#content" 
    }); 

    });
```

Hope this one helps you :-)

**EDIT:** Added missing ");"

Comment: How is that any different from what he had?

Comment: Hmm.. if I add the missing ); to yours it works! Any chance you could explain the difference?